# CSS3 animation translate3d not working

Tags: jquery, css, css-animations, translate3d

I have been experimenting with jQuery animate vs CSS3 animate, I alse wanted to test the 2D / 3D translate to see which is better.

Does anyone know why my CSS3 translate3d doesn't work? I've tried it on desktop and mobile.

Any help appreciated

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sygad/F6c4T/)

**HTML**

```
<div id="container1" class="container">transition</div>
    <div id="container2" class="container">translate</div>
    <div id="container3" class="container">translate3d</div>
    <div id="container4" class="container">jQ animate</div>
```

**CSS**

```
    .container          {position:absolute; left:20px; width:80px; height:80px; padding:5px;}

/* transition */
#container1         {top:20px; background:red;
                    -webkit-transition:all 0.3s linear;
                    -moz-transition:all 0.3s linear;
                    -o-transition:all 0.3s linear;
                    -ms-transition:all 0.3s linear;
                    transition:all 0.3s linear;}

#container1.on      {left:250px} /* It moves if from pos absolute of parent, the body tag in this example */



/* 2D translate */
#container2         {top:120px; background:yellow;
                    -webkit-transition:all 0.3s linear;
                    -moz-transition:all 0.3s linear;
                    -o-transition:all 0.3s linear;
                    -ms-transition:all 0.3s linear;
                    transition:all 0.3s linear;}

#container2.on      {-webkit-transform: translate(230px);
                    -moz-transform: translate(230px);
                    -o-transform: translate(230px);
                    -ms-transform: translate(230px);
                    transform: translate(230px);}  /* It moves if from the starting point, 20px left in this example */



/* 3D - translate */
#container3         {top:220px; background:lime;
                    -webkit-transition:all 0.3s linear;
                    -moz-transition:all 0.3s linear;
                    -o-transition:all 0.3s linear;
                    -ms-transition:all 0.3s linear;
                    transition:all 0.3s linear;}

#container3.on      {-webkit-transform: translate3d(230,0,0);
                    -moz-transform: translate3d(230,0,0);
                    -o-transform: translate3d(230,0,0);
                    -ms-transform: translate3d(230,0,0);
                    transform: translate3d(230,0,0);}  /* It moves if from the starting point, 20px left in this example */



/* jQuery Animate */
#container4         {top:320px; background:orange;}
```

**jQuery**

```
    $('#container1').click(function()
    {
        $(this).toggleClass('on');
    })

    $('#container2').click(function()
    {
        $(this).toggleClass('on');
    })

    $('#container3').click(function()
    {
        $(this).toggleClass('on');
    })

    $('#container4').toggle(function()
    {
        $(this).animate({'left':'250px'});

    }, function()
    {
        $(this).animate({'left':'20px'});
    })
```

Comment: Which browser are you using?

Comment: Desktop - chrome, safari, IE 7/8/9, FF

Comment: Android mobile - Chrome, Native, Opera Mobile, Firefox
iPhone 3Gs - native safari

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are missing the length unit `px`.

Use this in the css :

```
#container3.on {
    -webkit-transform: translate3d(230px, 0, 0);
    -moz-transform: translate3d(230px, 0, 0);
    -o-transform: translate3d(230px, 0, 0);
    -ms-transform: translate3d(230px, 0, 0);
    transform: translate3d(230px, 0, 0);
}  /* It moves if from the starting point, 20px left in this example */
```

Here is a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/F6c4T/6/)

Comment: Fantastic, thanks for that, can't believe I missed the total obvious.

Comment: translate 3d doesn't work in IE9 and the translate just jumps from the start to the end position, i.e. no animation......any ideas?

Comment: There is no support for ie9 : http://caniuse.com/#search=3dtransform

However, I've never used this, but apparently it uses css (transition) if available in the browser, otherwise uses jQuery animation as a fallback : http://addyosmani.com/blog/css3transitions-jquery/