# Move a element in the view using css

Tags: html, css, hover, move

I need to move an element when hovering over it in the view using only css for an exercise. I found some options but they didn't work.

```
<div>
<span class="hoverOver"> </span>
</div>
```

thanks in advance

EDIT: thanks for the answers.

I solved partially using the solution provided by Jaclyn Ciringione, with the :hover selector and using the solution provided in this post:
[CSS3 animation translate3d not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13361449/css3-animation-translate3d-not-working)

so I made a css like this:
(I had to move the class to the div to make it work as intended)

```css
.hoverOver{
-webkit-transition:all 0.3s linear;
-moz-transition:all 0.3s linear;
-o-transition:all 0.3s linear;
-ms-transition:all 0.3s linear;
transition:all 0.3s linear;}

.hoverOver:hover{
-webkit-transform: translate(230px);
-moz-transform: translate(230px);
-o-transform: translate(230px);
-ms-transform: translate(230px);
transform: translate(230px);}
```

```html
<div  class="hoverOver">
<span > I WANT TO MOVE</span>
</div>
```

Comment: Hello and welcome to StackOverflow. We will need more informations about what you need. And please provide your attemps, SO is not a programming service, especially if this is an exercice, we are not here to make it in your place.

Comment: What movement do you expect? Move where? Can you explain what do you want to achieve?

Comment: you're moving the element you're hovering? But if it moves too much you'll lose the hover

Comment: For starters you could search for CSS3 transitions and animations.

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. In addition to @Seblor'comment please read [how to ask questions](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [how to create a minimal example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) to improve your post

Comment: thanks edited with the updates

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can make it do anything you like by adding a hover class `:hover`

```
span.hoverOver:hover {
position: relative;
left: 20%;
}
```

Comment: The selector `div.hoverOver` will not match anything. The `span` has the class, not the `div`. Also you should wait for the OP to edit their question, because you cannot know if they want a solution like yours, or an animation or something else.

Comment: That is why in the explanation above the code snippet I said that you need to put the class on the div, not the span.... then I gave an example of how it would work when you do so.

Comment: Keeping the class on the span, without the `display` rule works well. Thanks for providing the 2 options though.